# Small issues after installing Gnome 3 (via PPA)

Tags: 11.04, gnome

After considering all the risks of using GNOME 3 in Ubuntu 11.04, I installed GNOME 3 via PPA. Fortunately, my system is working fine after the installation, but following are three issues which I want to fix.

- Evolution is still not updated to 3.0, thus it is using NotifyOSD to notify about new mails.
- Empathy is updated to 3.0 but is not using modern GNOME 3 notification system.
- Ubuntu still uses Old network manager instead of that of GNOME 3, thus, it is not integrated well with entire desktop.

Also, I wanted to know that how can I make Ubuntu 11.04 completely stock GNOME 3, including all the default applications that it is using.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 100% stock GNOME3 desktop, then I guess it won't be possible right now on Ubuntu. You have 2 options:

1) Live with those minor issues for a few more months, then move to Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric where you'll have stock GNOME3 + Shell as an option.

2) Change to another distro such as Fedora until Oneiric is ready with its thing.

BTW, why is notify-osd coming up? In my case the GNOME shell notifications come with Evolutions. Are you sure the notifications are notify-osd ones? Do they come at the top right or bottom right?

Comment: Ya, NotifyOSD is the one which manages Evolution's notifications, as I'm a fan of GNOME3's notification system, so I'm missing it with my "tweaked" system. About Fedora, well, I haven't used Fedora, and I wonder how it would be different from tweaking perspective, since all the experience about Linux that I have is only with Ubuntu. Can I try Arch with GNOME3? As I'm really eager to adopt GNOME 3, since Unity has disappointed me, so until Oneiric releases, I go for Arch.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Evolution 3.0 by two methods

1. By converting fedora 15 evolution3.0 rpm packages using alien.
2. By adding the debian experimental repository

   `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main`

As for the other two, its difficult to get as Ubuntu 11.04 is built on top of 2.32.
I have not compiled Gnome3 from source. Perhaps you could try that and see if it gives better result.

Comment: Why the -1? +1 from me to cancel the -1.